# JQueryのライブラリTABLEのヘッダ固定表示　fixedTblHdrLftColの使い方を教えて下さい

Tags: jquery

本件、[２テーブルの横幅と各列幅を双方で一致させたい（ヘッダ用テーブルとデータ次第で列幅可変のテーブル）](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50294/%ef%bc%92%e3%83%86%e3%83%bc%e3%83%96%e3%83%ab%e3%81%ae%e6%a8%aa%e5%b9%85%e3%81%a8%e5%90%84%e5%88%97%e5%b9%85%e3%82%92%e5%8f%8c%e6%96%b9%e3%81%a7%e4%b8%80%e8%87%b4%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84-%e3%83%98%e3%83%83%e3%83%80%e7%94%a8%e3%83%86%e3%83%bc%e3%83%96%e3%83%ab%e3%81%a8%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e6%ac%a1%e7%ac%ac%e3%81%a7%e5%88%97%e5%b9%85%e5%8f%af%e5%a4%89%e3%81%ae%e3%83%86%e3%83%bc%e3%83%96%e3%83%ab)の案件を達成するための課題から派生した問い合わせです。

TABLEのヘッダと左の列を固定表示（スライドバーを操作しても）する動作を達成したいです。fixedTblHdrLftColというプラグインを用いて対応しようとしており
プラグインをご提供頂いた方のサイトと、当プラグインをキーワードにStackoverflowを検索した結果、なんとか現況以下コーディングを果たし、
左から３列目までを固定表示することまでできました！！！
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

$(".exstrsv").fixedTblHdrLftCol({
    scroll: { width: w, height: h, leftCol: { fixedSpan: 3} }
});

しかし、ブラウザがIEであるためか、ヘッダが表示されてきません。
FireFoxのブラウザでは、一応にヘッダ表示されるも、左1列目のチェックボックスが操作しても、以前動作していた挙動が達成されなくなってしまいました。

上記コーディングで、相応のオプションを設定するか、HTMLのTHEAD要素にCLASSを追加するか何かでなんとかIEで、ヘッダを表示することはできないでしょうか？もう少しな雰囲気でして

試してみたら、という手立てのご提案でも構いません。諦めが悪くてすみません。

PS:
FixedMidashiというプラグインの採用もあるようですが、現況テーブルのデザインをわざわざTHEADとTBODYに区分けしているもので、このプラグインにもその方針が適用できるのか疑問に沸いており、方向転換を思いとどまっています

Comment: まず [作者のページ](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nkmrshn/20131220/1387495640) は確認されましたか？また、実際のスタイルシートやテーブル定義をどう記述しているかの情報がないと回答が付きづらいと思います。

Comment: cublickさん、いつもご支援・コメントをありがとうございます。
実は作者のページを「ひと目」見て、難しそう！！という所感を抱き問合せさせて頂きました。

中断で表示されたモノトーンの表に、option1・option2・option3とありますが、
これら項目についてStyleSheetを定義してデザインを決めるということなのですかね？？
そう考えると、
そもそも当該テーブルは2つのDIVの中に収めるべき（INNER・OUTER）なのか？
とか、このページだけではよく分からなくて

Comment: 作者のページを拝見しましたが、optionの設定の仕方が分かりません。どなたかご教示を頂けませんでしょうか..

Comment: 本日までEclipseのブラウザをIEに設定していましたが、Firefoxに切替えてみました。
やはり、動作に替わりはなく現況の自分のコーディング（オプション設定）に問題があるのかな、
という状況です。

Comment: コメントは直前までにコメントしたユーザ宛てにしか通知が飛ばないのでご注意ください。追加で分かった情報などがあれば [本文] を編集してもらった方がリストの上位に上がるので目には付きやすくなります。 / こちらの質問はライブラリを限定した質問なので、よく知られたライブラリでもない限り回答は付きづらいのではないかと思います。

Comment: 貴重なご見解をありがとうございます、コメント追記の挙動、初めて知りました。
fixed_midashiにしようかな、正直なんでもよくて

一先ずfixed_midashiを試して駄目だったら本文に追記を図ります。